# How to get the derivative of an average?

Tags: derivatives

I was curious about how to derive the derivative of an average. More specifically:

$$\mu = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i = 1}^m x_i$$

$$\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial x_i} =\ ?$$

My derivation is as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\mu & = \frac{1}{m}(x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_m) \\
\partial \mu / \partial x_i& = \frac{1}{m}(1 + 1+\dots + 1) \\
& = 1
\end{align}
$$

but I'm not sure if this is correct...

Comment: The answer is $\frac  1 m$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're close. However, you made one mistake: Your partial differentiation wasn't partial. All variables except $x_i$ should disappear (become $0$). For instance, for three variables, I'm sure you know that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x+y+z)=1+0+0
$$
rather than $1+1+1$. Calling them $x_1,x_2,x_3$ rather than $x,y,z$ doesn't change this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Then does that mean for the case that I've showed, since we're differentiating w.r.t. a specific single $x_i$, rather than $1/m \times (1 + 1 + \cdots + 1)$ it would be $1/m \times 1$, right?

Comment: @Seankala Exactly! And I'm sure you've seen this in action: if you increase one of the variables by $1$, how much does the average change?